# How to set the height of material ui tooltip according to the tool tip content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the material ui tooltip and I want the height of the tooltip to grow according to the content inside the tip. Currently, the text inside the tooltip is overflowing when I use the below code for styling the tooltip.

```
const LightTooltip = withStyles(theme => ({
tooltip: {
    backgroundColor: "#8031A7",
    color: "white",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
    fontSize: 11,
    // width: '232px',
    marginLeft: '38px',
    flex: 'none',
    order: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    flexGrow: 0,
    height: '100%'

},
arrow: {
    color: "#8031A7",

},

}))(MaterialTooltip);
```

Is there any way to make the height auto grow with respect to the content?

Comment: I guess you can just set the width, then the height would be flexible.

Comment: Setting the width is not making the height flexible